# Update a field just another one has some condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update a row in any case except an specific field should just be update if another one has some condition.

In this case an example is when i want to update an article. The `articles` table has 5 columns(id, caption, content, publishdate, published) that `published` is boolean.

Now i want an specific row to be update in any case but `publishdate` should be update just if `published` is true. I want it in one single query.

Is there a way to do such thing ?

**edit**
I want to check value of `published` in query, not in database. something like:

```
UPDATE articles SET (published AS b) = true, publishdate = (b==true? 'new date': b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `inline IF` statement. eg

```
UPDATE articles
SET publishedDate = IF(published = 1, 'new date HERE', publishedDate)
-- WHERE condition here
```

this assumes that `1 = true`, if you store boolean as string then `IF(published = 'true',...`

**UPDATE 1**

```
-- assumes 0 = false, 1 = true
SET @status := 1;
SET @newDate := CURDATE();

UPDATE articles
SET publishedDate = IF(1 = @status, @newDate, publishedDate),
    published = @status
-- WHERE condition here
```

Comment: But this check current value of `published` in database. i want to check `published` value in query. Sorry if i made confusion.

Comment: How about `publishedDate = IF(@status = 1, @newDate, publishedDate)` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE articles
SET publishdate = CASE WHEN published = 1 THEN <new value> ELSE publishdate END 
    [, ...]
[WHERE ...]
```

---

If you want to check a parameter value instead then you can do that as well:

```
UPDATE articles
SET publishdate = CASE WHEN @published = 1 THEN <new value> ELSE publishdate END 
    [, ...]
[WHERE ...]
```

Comment: But this check current value of `published` in database. i want to check `published` value in query. Sorry if i made confusion.